# Are properties always immutable?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm currently experiencing an issue when using an auto-generated property for a class member. Calling a method on the class should update the property, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm updating some old C# code and VS2017 advises me few refactoring tips, for instance, private members with manually provided properties to auto-generated properties.

VS makes this easy with a couple of clicks, and everything compiles just fine.
The problem is that code does not work as before.

Consider the following reduced code example:

```
using System;

public class Program    
{
    struct A
    {
        public A(int x) : this()
        {
            X = x;
        }

        public int X { get; private set; }

        public void Update(int y)
        {
            X += y;
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        private A _secondVar;

        public B()
        {
        }

        public A MyVar { get; set; }

        public A SecondVar
        {
            get { return _secondVar; }
            protected set { _secondVar = value; }
        }           

        public void Foo(int z)
        {
            MyVar.Update(z);
            _secondVar.Update(z);
        }       
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE: b.MyVar: " + b.MyVar.X + ", b.SecondVar: " + b.SecondVar.X );
        b.Foo(23);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER: b.MyVar: " + b.MyVar.X + ", b.SecondVar: " + b.SecondVar.X );
    }
}
```

**The output is:**

```
BEFORE: b.MyVar: 0, b.SecondVar: 0
AFTER: b.MyVar: 0, b.SecondVar: 23
```

I would expect that calling `MyVar.Update(z)` would update the property, and subsequent calls to `MyVar.X` should provide the updated value.

Is this expected behavior, or a bug in C#?

Comment: What output did you **expect**, and why?

Comment: creating a struct is relatively rare, in the grand scheme of things; *mutable* structs are virtually **never** a good idea (although I'd allow it for a `ref struct`); if you're using recent C# versions, virtually all structs should be declared `readonly struct`

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'd also emphasize that "virtually never" isn't *quite* never. I support the `ValueTuple` family being mutable, although it took me a while to get on board.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed - I was quite deliberate in my hedging :) But it is one of those things where the awkward answer is : "you need to *really, really* understand 
 exactly the what, the why, and the consequences"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using mutable structs, which is strongly discouraged for precisely this reason.

Your code here:

```
public void Foo(int z)
{
    MyVar.Update(z);
    _secondVar.Update(z);
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
public void Foo(int z)
{
    A tmp = MyVar; // Creates a copy
    tmp.Update(z);
    _secondVar.Update(z);
}
```

Your `_secondVar.Update(z)` code changes the value of `_secondVar` because you're calling it directly on a variable. That's not the case with your property - using a property getter is effectively calling a method that returns a value, which is a copy of the variable value.

If you were to use classes, you'd see the behaviour you expect, because then you wouldn't be trying to change the value of the underlying variable, but change the content within the object it refers to.

Comment: perhaps worth noting (but not worth me adding an answer): recent versions of C# make it *really easy* to not make the mistake of mutable structs: `readonly struct A
    {
        public A(int x) => X = x;
        public int X { get; }
    }`